# For which value of $t$ does following integral converge $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{{3x^2-t}} - \frac{t}{{2x+1}} dx $?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

I am trying to find *for which value of **t***, the following integral converges (and where it converges):

$$ \text {Let} \ t \in \mathbb{R}$$

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{{3x^2-t}} - \frac{t}{{2x+1}} dx \ \ \ \ (1)$$

---

#### My attempt

Let's consider the second part of the integral only and by that I mean $$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{t}{{2x+1}} dx  $$
Now

$$\text{Let}\ u = 2x + 1$$

$$\text{Then}\ dx = \frac{1}{2} du $$
$$\text{and}\ \int_{0}^{\infty} \to \int_{1}^{\infty} $$

$$ \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{t}{2u} du= \frac{t}{2}\left[ \ln(u)\right]^{+\infty}_1 = +\infty$$

Therefore it seems that this diverges, no matter what's the t value. 
Therefore the initial integral (1) diverges too. 
What is the mistake in this approach?

Comment: $\int [f(t)-g(t)]dt$ can converge even if $\int g(t)dt$ does not. [Example $f=g$].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x+1}{{3x^2-t}} - \frac{t}{{2x+1}} dx \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{2x^2+3x+1 - 3tx^2+t^2}{(3x^2-t)(2x+1)} dx \ \ \ \ (1)$$

$$ I = \int_{0}^{\infty}  \frac{2x^2+3x+1 - 3tx^2+t^2}{(3x^2-t)(2x+1)} dx \ \ \ \ (1)$$

for this integral to converge, considering that it is a rational function we must have $deg(2x^2+3x+1 - 3tx^2+t^2) \leq deg((3x^2-t)(2x+1)) -2 = 1.$

Therefore $deg(2x^2+3x+1 - 3tx^2+t^2) \leq 1$ i.e : $2=3t$ or $t=\frac {2}{3}.$

Now we see what happens around our value of $t$:

$$\frac{2x^2+3x+1 - 3tx^2+t^2}{(3x^2-t)(2x+1)}$$ is equivalent to 
$$\frac{\sqrt2+1+\frac{4}{9}}{(3x^2-\frac{2}{3})(2(\sqrt2 /3)+1)}$$

which clearly is not convergent around $x=\frac{\sqrt2}{3}.$

In conclusion the integral does not converge ever

Comment: ``for this integral to converge, considering that it is a rational function we must have deg(2x2+3x+1−3tx2+t2)≤deg((3x2−t)(2x+1))−2=1`` Could you please explain this a little more? What's the theorem behing this? @Mohammed

Comment: You need to see what happens when x tends to infinity the rational fraction become equivalent to $1/x^{-deg(2x2+3x+1−3tx2+t2)+deg((3x2−t)(2x+1))}$, and we conclude that in order of your integral to not have a prolem around infinity  you need  that condition, Read about Riemann integral

Comment: I know what a Riemann integral is, thank you. But why does the rational fraction become equivalent to $$ \frac {1}{x^{−deg(2x2+3x+1−3tx2+t2)+deg((3x2−t)(2x+1)}} $$ on infinity?  There is something I am not getting here. Apparenly it is equivalent to a p-integral etc. But why? @Mohammed

Comment: $-deg(2x2+3x+1−3tx2+t2)+deg((3x2−t)(2x+1)= 3-deg(2x2+3x+1−3tx2+t2)) $ is actually inferior to  2 (depending on whether or not $2x^2−3tx2$ is zero or not ) if it is strictly inferior 2 we have a problem, so it must be equal to 2, i.e  $2x^2−3tx2$ is zero for all $x$

Answer (score 1):

HINT :

You can write the integrand as
$$
\frac{t^2-3tx^2+2x^2+3x+1}{\left(2x+1\right)\left(3x^2-t\right)}
$$
So that you can prove there's no problem in 0 or in $+\infty$ by finding an equivalent which form is like $1/u^{\alpha}$.